# How do I build a state space model of a given phenomenon?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, control-theory

I am a control engineering student and I would like to create a state space model of a given real world problem. The idea is to consider something that can be experienced in the real world, for example, the cultivation of wheat every year, or something of this kind.

I would like to model such types of problems using a state space model of the form

$$\dot{x}=Ax+Bu$$

or, in the nonlinear case, using

$$\dot{x}=f(x)+g(x)u$$

How can I do such modeling?

Comment: Are you sure these can be modelled linearly?

Comment: not really sure that these can be modelled linearly, I just would like to learn how these models are created in general, so both linear and non linear case. It is more a curiosity to be honest.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I totally agree, thank you

Comment: The first step would be to model the system using ODEs (or difference equations). Then you rewrite in state space form. To model the phenomenon, you may need to have some knowledge of the domain. I do not believe it is possible to create good models of physical, chemical or biological phenomena without any knowledge of physics, chemistry and biology, respectively.

Comment: For example, if you're interested in medicine, take a look at [this](http://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-75847-3) and [this](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-79388-7).